# Как правильно вставить toast в smali листинг?

Tags: java, android, reverse-engineering, smali

Пытаюсь разобраться в функции генерации запросов в приложении. В запросе в параметре передается MD5-строка. Генерится она вот так (.class):

```
paramSession = dh.a(dh.a(paramSession) + dh.a(str2));
```

smali:

```
invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/avito/android/util/dh;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v3, v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

invoke-static {v9}, Lcom/avito/android/util/dh;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v3

invoke-virtual {v0, v3}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->append(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;

move-result-object v0

invoke-virtual {v0}, Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;->toString()Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0

invoke-static {v0}, Lcom/avito/android/util/dh;->a(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;

move-result-object v0
```

Где: `dh.a` - `MD5` функция.

`paramSession` - некий secretKey

`str2` - `urlEncodedParams`.

C `urlEncodeParams` подбором разберусь. А вот что за secretKey - не ясно. В переменную эту напихивается то url, то хост.

Хочу попробовать вставить `toast`, в текст которого я засуну строку `paramSession`.

Код toast(smali):

```
const/4 v10, 0x1

const-string v8, "YOUR MESSAGE @ iOSGods.com"

invoke-static {p0, v8, v10}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->makeText(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;I)Landroid/widget/Toast;

move-result-object v10

invoke-virtual {v10}, Landroid/widget/Toast;->show()V
```

Не знаю как правильно сунуть код `toast`-a в листинг. Собранное приложение постоянно вылетает. Пробовал менять регистры (думал занимаю нужные). Какие еще могут быть проблемы? Может его можно вставлять лишь в определенном месте или что-то вроде того. 
Есть ли иной способ получить интересные мне строки до оборачивания их в MD5?

Comment: Что лежит в `p0`? `Toast.makeText` требует  `Context` первым аргументом. Если контекст не доступен из этого метода, то тост показать не выйдет. Лог или `System.out` можно использовать везде, но смотреть нужно с помощью LogCat.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста smali-код для Лог/System.out

Comment: `invoke-static {v0, v1}, Landroid/util/Log;->i(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I`

Comment: Спасибо. Буду пробовать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы сделать инъекцию кода, проще всего вставлять одиночный вызов статик-метода и передавая все нужное уже туда. Именно такой метод предоставляет собой Log.i(). Если класса Log мало, к примеру, хотим сделать Тосты или записать данные в файл, то пишем свой класс со статик-методами, которые будем дергать. Само собой, вся инициализация должна быть статичной. Если надо какой-то стейт, то делаем синглтон живость которого (например, для внешнего сокета) проверяем на каждом вызове. У такого метода есть недостаток: размер кода у метода не должен превышать 65кб, что в общем-то редко, но встреается, к примеру, в гугловых библиотеках. Остается только положить рядом смали-класс с реализацией методов или инъектнуть нужные классы через dx и можно запускать.

Comment: Интересно. К сожалению, с java знаком плохо. Но общую мысль я уловил. Попробую)

Comment: Есть пара вопросов:
1. После того, как я положу smali класс рядом с нужными мне классами. Нужно ли как-то подключать мой класс или он автоматически получит тот же namespace(Сишный термин, не знаю как в java с этим). 
2. Что такое dx? Есть ли мануалы по инъекции через него?

Comment: А что, в сишке появились неймспейсы? dx утилитка из сдк для работы с классами, мануалов по инъекциям можно найти в разных блогах, про инклюды уже не помню, но что мешает посмотреть шапку файла?

Comment: в c# есть. Так значит инклюды все таки будут нужны(скорее всего). Оки, сделаем по аналогии)

Comment: Ну хоть не в 1сишке.

Comment: Ну не надо меня троллить(

Comment: А вы тут и непричем. Это я работу пытаюсь найти, а некоторые работодатели прямо через слеш и пишут. Значит    c/c++/c#/1c - это одно и тоже

Comment: Да! Все получилось. Пришлось попотеть без знаний java и навыков работы с со всем этим арсеналом, но в результате создал класс с методом, который в текстовик выписвает все что мне нужно. 
Поставить на Андроид Студио smalidea у меня не вышло, так что я просто собрал приложение и дизассемблировал его для получения smali-кода. Положил рядом в чужую apk. В самом файле, необходимо было заменить пути(обращения к функциям). Собирал через APK Studio - хорошая вещь, ошибки компиляции нормально выдает. Но подписывать приложение не умеет(или не нашел). Подписывал через apktool.